# Does OS perform optimization of TCP/IP when used locally

Tags: linux, windows, tcp, ipc

I am building cross-platform application, consisting of several modules, exchanging with each other.

That means my question is related to both **Windows** and **Linux**.

**Q**: If using `TCP/IP` for inter-process communication, is there any kind of special optimization, performed by OS in case **both endpoints** are on localhost?

Somewhere I've heard, in this case Windows can bypass network drivers and use just shared memory. I have no idea about the source/proof of this statement, but the idea to switch off some unused stuff sounds logic.

Is that true and if yes, where I can read the details?

Comment: They do, but unfortunately can't point you to details (in Windows it might not even be a public information).